# Prove that for all $n\ge9$, there exist natural numbers $x,y$ such that $n=2x+5y$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

How would you use induction to prove this?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: note that if $n\geq 9$ is written as $n=2x+5y$, then either $y\geq 1$ or $x\geq 2$. If the former, write
$$
n+1=(2x+5y)+(2\cdot 3-5)=2(x+3)+5(y-1);
$$
if the latter, write
$$
n+1=(2x+5y)+(2\cdot(-2)+5)=2(x-2)+5(y+1).
$$

Comment: +1, but a little more care is needed. In the first case, if $y=1$, then $y-1=0$, which is not a natural number. (I know it's a matter of opinion, but I'm sure in this problem natural numbers start with $1$.) Similarly with $(x-2)$ in the second case.

Comment: @zipirovich The problem implicitly assumes $0$ is a natural number because otherwise the claim is false for $n=10$.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see that... You're right! But then, I wonder why they didn't start with $n\ge 4$. But that's a question for "them", not for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $n=9$ then $n = 2\cdot 2 + 5\cdot 1$; taking $x:= 2$ and $y:=1$ suffices.
If $n \geq 9$ is an integer such that
$n-1= 2x + 5y$ for some integers $x,y > 0$, then
$n = n-1 + 1 = 2x+5y + 1 = 2x' + 5y'$.
Note that $2x+5y+1 = 2x+5y+(5-4) = 2(x-2) + 5(y+1)$.
So the preceding equalities are equivalent to
$$
n = 2x' + 5y' = 2(x-2) + 5(y+1).
$$
Taking $x' := x-2$ and $y' := y+1$ suffices,
which are still integers.

Note that for $n=10$ we have $x' = 2-2 = 0$, which is not a natural number if you don't count $0$ as one such.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including zero as a natural number?  I think it has to be to get 10

since  9 = 2 x 2 + 1 x 5

we can always make another 1 to add on with 5 - 2x2.  If the number is even it can always be 2x, so to make the next odd number we can always take 2 from x and add set y = 1, for ever